# Distinct count of custom dimensions in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, custom-dimensions

I've set up a custom dimension in Google Analytics and I'd like to plot the count of unique values tracked in this custom dimension per day. Is this possible using the Google Analytics website or do I need to do something custom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Analytis does not count the distinct values per day of any metric.   You would need to use the API, or export data to spreadsheet software.